# How to send error from HttpPost to Callout if ExternalID is the same?

Tags: apex, callout, rest, httpresponse, httppost

I have an Item object in Org2 that I can post from Org1 (in Org1 is Tool object that passes its fields to THIS (Item) object). Item has ExternalID field that takes the ID from Tool. How can I send an error to Callout if Item with this ExternalID is already posted?

```
@HttpPost
global static Item__c post() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;          
    Item__c item = new Item__c();
    //Here we get our Item record with ExternalID already:
    String body = req.requestBody.toString();
    RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
    RestContext.response = res;

    try{
        it = (Item__c)JSON.deserialize(body, Item__c.class);
        insert item;
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(item));
        res.statusCode = 200;
        return item;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
    } 
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do SOQL query on `Item__c` filtering by `ExternalID__c` field. If result is not empty, then set `statusCode` to relevant one. You can find list of all status codes [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm).

---

do not set `RestContext.response.responseBody` and use `return` at same time, as `return` result will be set as response body.

> - If the method returns void, then Apex REST returns the response in the responseBody property.
> - If the method returns a value, then Apex REST serializes the return value as the response.

also I suggest you to set some message in body, if such external Id already exists

```
@HttpPost
global static void post() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.Request;          
    String body = req.requestBody.toString();
    Item__c item = (Item__c)JSON.deserialize(body, Item__c.class);
    RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
    if([
        select Id
        from Item__c
        where ExternalID__c = :item.ExternalID__c
        limit 1
    ].isEmpty()){
        insert item;
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(item));
    }else{
        response.statusCode = 409; // CONFLICT status code
        response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Item with External Id ' + item.ExternalID__c + 'already exists');
    }
    RestContext.response = response;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this thing can't back error msg. If I do with try/catch - no probs with that. On another side I use `throw new MeException` for errors on VF page. Maybe because of that? And I get there statuscode 200 anyway